# Random number to be used as index in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, indexing, numbers

Well I am unable to get the integer index for the vector packet_send. ( Basically I am generating a random index between 1 to 100). When I saw the class of "lengths" which I am using as index it is double, that means rand function returns double value, so I tired converting it to integer by typecasting it to int16. But still I am not getting the desired lengths, so that I can use it as index for the vector.

```
for time_slot = 1:1:number_of_slots    
       p = randint(1)*prob;
        lengths =int16( round(rand(1) * max_length)); % lengths value between 1 to 100.. as per the range decided
        if (p == prob)
            packet_send(lengths) = packet_send(lengths) + 1;
            total_number_of_packets = total_number_of_packets + 1 ;
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/randi.html?searchHighlight=randi) to create random integers. For your code example, this could read:

```
lengths = randi(max_length, 1);
```

You could also draw all the random indices before the loop starts with:

```
allLengths = randi(max_length, number_of_slots);
```

**~edit~**
If `randi` is not available in your version of matlab, you can use:

```
lengths = floor(rand(1)*max_length)+1;
```

Comment: getting an error , undefined function or method 'randi' for input arguments of type double. I am using lengths = randi(100,1)

Comment: Why do you feed a double into the function? I would guess that both `max_length` and `number_of_slots` are integers, right?

Comment: I am using matlab 7.6.0 ( R200a) when I searched for randi in help i did find nothing :(

Comment: where do i feed double ? well i dont know if matlab takes 100 and 1 as double instead of int, this is my day 1 with matlab

Comment: The problem is that your matlab version does not contain the function `randi`. Will edit my answer.

Comment: lengths is still double , this cant be used as index. floor's return value is double in my case

Comment: any other answers ... the version is stil not supporting , lengths is still double , this cant be used as index. floor's return value is double in my case

Comment: Sorry, I thought that your problem was random number generation rather than type-casting. What's wrong with `int16` to cast integer types?

Comment: it is not accepting those values . :( i think i will have to upgrade the matlab..

Comment: Thanks for all your comments

Comment: Please note that `randi` also returns `double` typed results, although they contain integer values. Hence, updating will not help you.

Comment: It could be helpful if you make your question more specific. What is the error message you get? Which types does `packet_send` expect as a input etc.

Comment: subscript indices must have either be real positive integers or logicals : Error at Packet_send(lengths) = Packet_send(lengths) + 1;

Comment: can u just tell how to get a random integer number from 1 to 100 which can be used as index.

Comment: This seems not to be an type issue, but rather the value of `lengths` is negative or zero. Make sure that `lengths` is greater than zero. For your specific problem, I would guess that the variable `max_length` is either zero or negative.

Comment: ya but **lengths** is the variable to which i am assigning a random number from 0 to 100.

Comment: If `length` equals zero, would will get exactly the error message you just posted.

Comment: how can i like all your answers 100 times :)